# not displaying old value when editing cell in a QTableWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidget

I have a basic QTableWidget, created with this python code:

```
from silx.gui import qt
app = qt.QApplication([])
qtw = qt.QTableWidget()
qtw.show()
qtw.setColumnCount(8)
qtw.setRowCount(7)
app.exec_()
```

The `from silx.gui import qt` line is just a wrapper that finds out the installed qt wrapper (PyQt4, PyQt5 or PySide) and flattens the qt namespace.

The resulting table has a strange behavior when I edit a cell: as expected, the old text is highligted when I double-click the cell, but the unusual behavior is that the old text remains visible and the new text overlaps with the old one while I'm typing it, until I press enter or I click another cell.

I would like the old text to disappear as soon as I start typing the new one. I know it's possible, because I have an example of program that features a qTableWidget with the behavior I would like to have.

But I cannot find where in that program the cell editing behavior is altered. How can I do this?

Example of "spam" and "eggs" overlayed.

[[image: example of "spam" and "eggs" overlayed[1]]

EDIT: the code sample without the wrapper business

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QTableWidget, qVersion
app =QApplication([])
print(qVersion())
qtw = QTableWidget()
qtw.show()
qtw.setColumnCount(8)
qtw.setRowCount(7)
app.exec_()
```

With PyQt4, use this import (also remove the `print(qVersion())` line):

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTableWidget
```

Comment: did You try Your code after importing the qt wrapper as usual. After import of PyQt5 its working as expected.

Comment: I tried that, I didn't solve the issue. I tested PyQt4/ Qt 4.8.6 and PyQt5 / Qt 5.3.2.

Comment: @PiRK. I can't reproduce this using PyQt-4.11.4/Qt-4.8.7 or PyQt-5.7/Qt-5.7. It looks like a bug to me. Are you able to reproduce the problem by viewing a similar example in Qt Designer? Maybe you should also try with some different style plugins.

Comment: I see the same issue when playing with a qtablewidget in Qt designer.

Comment: Interesting discovery : I played around with the other program that has the proper behavior. When the widget is called from that complex program, the cells behave the way we want them to. But when I load the widget on it's own, I have the same problem as my example.

Comment: So I tried to put my example inside a QMainWindow, or in a layout, but with no luck so far. :( Anyway, it's probably a glitch or a conflict on my machine. Maybe too many Qt and/or PyQt versions installed.

Comment: @PiRK. If you see the same issue in Qt Designer, it must either be a bug in Qt, or the widget style plugin you are using. I suspect it may be the latter. What one are you using? Have you tried using a different widget style?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the existence of widget style plugins. How can I find out which one I'm using? My OS is Debian 8, btw.

Answer (score 2):

My method:

```
class MyDelegate(QItemDelegate):

    def setEditorData(self,editor,index):
        editor.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        editor.setText(index.data().toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, edit behavior is controlled via `QItemDelegates`.  Typically, this is done to provide more advanced editing, or to filter input data or perform some side effects (like update a database) when edits are made.  But you can also use it to just clear the editor presented to the user when editing.

```
class MyDelegate(QItemDelegate):

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        # Normally, this would set the text of the editor to the current
        # value of the cell.  If you do nothing here, it will be blank.
        editor.clear()

qtw = QTableWidget()
delegate = MyDelegate(qtw)
qtw.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

Comment: Thanks for that information. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to change the behavior of my table.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, above problem comes when I set background color of QWidgetTable to transparent. When I remove the setting, there is no old data overlays the new one anymore. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try connecting the signal emited by QTableWidget `cellClicked(int row, int column)` with a slot created for clearing the entry. 
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#connecting-disconnecting-and-emitting-signals

Comment: Wouldn't that delete my data everytime I try to select it (e.g for copying the value)?